# Django - where to initialize static objects?

Tags: django

I need to manage a DB connection pool outside of Django's model framework.

Where is 'right' place to initialize objects like this (so that the entire application has access to the same object), and a 2nd requirement is the ability to close my connections when django/python is shutdown.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Django inits its own Connection object (a proxy to the correct type) in django.db.**_*init*_**.py
So, it looks like it would not be that a bad idea to initialize yours in the **_*init*_** of your personal app.

Django registers a signal when it closes its connection, so just catch this signal to close your connection. The following code is taken from django.db.**_*init*_**.py

```
# Register an event that closes the database connection
# when a Django request is finished.
def close_connection(**kwargs):
    for conn in connections.all():
        conn.close()
signals.request_finished.connect(close_connection)
```

Answer (score 0):

For your second requirement:

Djano registers a signal to close connection

[https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/**init**.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/__init__.py)